# UNC Path to photos on iPhone on Windows XP

Tags: iphone, command-line, software-rec, photos, unc

I would like to manipulate (copy and/or move) the photos I took with my iPhone from the command line or a Perl script.  But when I plug the iPhone, it doesn't get a drive letter: in 'My Computer', it's displayed in the 'Scanners and Cameras' group, instead of the 'Devices with Removable Storage'.

What is the UNC path to the photos on my phone?  Or, alternatively, how can I configure the iPhone or Windows so that the latter gives a drive letter to the former?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only retrieve the photos from the iPhone, you cannot write to it. Further more, iPhone identifies itself to Windows as a [PTP device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol), and hence

> PTP does not specify a way for objects
>   to be stored – it is a communication
>   protocol. Nor does it specify a
>   transport layer.
>   Images on digital cameras are
>   generally stored as files on a mass
>   storage device, such as a memory card,
>   which is formatted with a file system,
>   most commonly FAT or FAT 32, which may
>   be laid out as per the Design rule for
>   Camera File system (DCF)
>   specification. **However, none of these**
>   **are required, as PTP abstracts from**
>   **the underlying representation**.

So in short I don't think its possible to assign a UNC path to it.

Ed:

On further searching I found a software, [PTPDrive](http://www.ptpdrive.com/). I haven't tested it personally, you can try your luck.