# MTP File Browser For Windows XP

Tags: mp3, mtp

I have a samsung T10 (4 GB) mp3 player that is recognized by windows XP as an MTP device, and then I can sync it using both WMP and winamp. However, it does not appear under the file explorer as a mass storage device. I know that this is expected behaviour (it is, after all, not a UMS device). However, I am looking for a workaround that'll allow me to access my MP3 player as a USB mass storage device.

Googling wasn't very helpful. [mtpfs](http://www.adebenham.com/mtpfs/) seems to do exactly what I want, but it is for the *nixes. Can anybody suggest a windows solution to 'mount' a MTS device under windows explorer. Thanks :!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've patched mine -

Patching a T10.

This is the easiest way to do it, I think

Grab the tcctool-win32.zip and unzip it to a simple folder say in drive C:\ , I just use "la" only because at that time I did not know how to spell LaFleur
tcctool link
http://haxx.rockbox.org/utils/tcctool/tcctool-win32.zip
Or say use msc a folder name if you are using that version.
Use Winzip its far better to use.
http://www.winzip.com/index.htm
Then get hold of patch_it.bat and copy that to the same folder.
patch_it.bat link
http://uploaded.to/?id=49lxrp
Get the T10 Firmware files from here
http://www.emodio.com/download/DownloadList.action

Unzip the files to the same directory as above and also to the DATA directory of the T10, I had a MTP US firmware, if you are using MSC firmware copy the 2 files to the root/base of the T10, ie, the drive letter of the T10.

This is what it looks like for me using the LaFleur Firmware version
C:\la\tcctool-driver-win32
C:\la\patch_it.bat
C:\la\readme.txt
C:\la\T10V.ROM
C:\la\T10V.RSC
C:\la\tcctool.exe
C:\la\tcctool-windows.txt

Then hold the power button and press the reset button
release the power button when your PC shows "new device/hardware found"
Do not let windows search for the driver, you must select it manually, you should point to this location as in my case C:\la\tcctool-driver-win32
After that is done just double click on patch_it.bat, I then got a dos window and after download finished , I got a paused message and to hit any key.

I think this is a lot easier than using the Run/Cmd thing.

P.S dont forget to backup your T10 files first, before you do the format thing.

Comment: thanks for the pointers. will definitely try that tonight, and let you know if it worked.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!
I used the MSC version of the firmware (I used the Jellymon theme - see the complete list at http://www.emodio.com/support/download/downloadfile/html_MSC/t10gui_list.html). For more detailed instructions, see http://www.anythingbutipod.com/forum/showthread.php?t=30116

Also, updating the firmware opened up a lot of bluetooth options, besides making the YP-T10 a mass storage device. I even went ahead and installed the games availiable on the samsung site. yay!

Comment: @KnickerKicker anytime dude

Answer (score 2):

I'd posted earlier about [mounting a PTP device as a mass storage device](https://superuser.com/questions/67875/unc-path-to-photos-on-iphone-on-windows-xp/68216#68216), however I can't seem to find any software (yet) for a MTP device.
 I did, however find a [blog entry about a workaround](http://open-blog.net/mtp-device-on-windows-as-drive-unit/) that you can try:

> so I looked for a while, and of
>   course, in this operating system was a
>   little “trick” of how, here they are
>   behaving:
>
> 1. Right click on My Computer and go to properties
> 2. Go to Hardware tab
> 3. Open Device Manager
> 4. Search within the portable device, right click to yours and
>      select `Update Driver`
> 5. When `Internet Connection` pops-up, choose `not now` and then
>      `next`
> 6. Then click the radio buttom `Install from a list or specific
>      location`. And finally in the next
>      window, select the option `Do not
>      search, select the driver to use` and
>      click the Next button
> 7. We double click on `Mass Storage Device` and click on `Finish`.
> 8. With this we finished, we ask to restart, once done, to connect the
>      device automatically appear in My
>      Computer as a normal flash drive

Comment: I tried your method, but the device manager won't display any other device except the 'MTP Device' option. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Great job! worked for me:)